# What is causing my PHP curl requests to time out?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

So I have a PHP script that posts a large file to a remote API. But whenever the response takes longer than about 200 seconds to come back, then I just get a content-length of zero in the response. This never used to happen before we moved our server to a new hosting provider, so I think that the problem is related to the Apache or PHP configuration. I've tried to set every variable in our PHP and Apache config to longer periods of time than 180 sec., but still this keeps happening.

I turned on debugging in our Apache logging and this is what I see:

```
* About to connect() to xml.myservice.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 555.555.555.555... * connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using RC4-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=MyState; L=MyCity; O=My Service Corporation; CN=xml.myservice.com
*        start date: 2014-02-13 18:26:02 GMT
*        expire date: 2015-03-25 23:59:58 GMT
*        subjectAltName: xml.myservice.com matched
*        issuer: C=BE; O=GlobalSign nv-sa; CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - G2
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /xmlservlet HTTP/1.1^M
Host: xml.myservice.com^M
> POST /xmlservlet HTTP/1.1^M
Host: xml.myservice.com^M
Accept: */*^M
Content-Type: text/xml^M
Content-Length: 10773^M
Expect: 100-continue^M
^M
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue^M
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK^M
< Cache-Control: private^M
< Content-Type: text/xml^M
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5^M
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319^M
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET^M
< Date: Mon, 29 Sep 2014 21:03:26 GMT^M
< Content-Length: 0^M
< ^M
```

(for reference this connection attempt began at 21:00:05)

I strongly suspect that the problem is that the destination server that I'm making the request from occasionally takes longer than 200 seconds to respond (it's normally averaging around 170-190 sec.), and that my own server is timing out the request prematurely and returning a zero content length to PHP in these cases.

Any tips on where I should look in the Apache or PHP config files to fix this? I want to know where I can look to extend how long my server will wait for a response. I want it to double the amount of time it waits for responses.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any error in curl? It really looks like a socket timeout.

Comment: Does it work with an actual `/bin/curl` command?